# Overwrite conflict app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, static-pages

I am trying to create a static page.  I typed `$ rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework` and got the output below.

```
    conflict  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
Overwrite   
/Users/themaktravels/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb?   (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] d
  class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
-   def ...
+   def home
+   end
+ 
+   def help
    end
  end
Retrying...
```

I tried to see what the difference is, but I am not familiar with this to understand what the difference is.  When I tried to not overwrite the file and then tested the URL, I got this error on my page.

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I then tried to checkout my changes with GIT and then tried to run rake routes

```
bundle update rake

bundle show rake 

require 'rake/dsl_definition'
```

But my static page still shows an error.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: what did u get when do rake routes ? you have an error saying no routes matches most probably you don't have mention any routes in routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your routes file

*config/routes.rb*

```
get "static_pages/home"
get "static_pages/help"
```

HTH